# SQL Sever - max # of 8k pages in a file?

Tags: sql-server

MSDN says here: [msdn maximums](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) that max datafile size is "16 Terabytes" - not sure if their definition of terabyte is 1024^4 or 1000^4 - so valid max page number might be 2,147,483,648 (for 1024 basis) or 1,953,125,000 (for 1000 basis) or perhaps something else -  does anyone know with certainty?

I have heard that this limit should be increasing with future releases - right now I'm using 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is based on 1024 which is a kilobyte. Multiply that by 1024 and you get a megabyte. And so on.

Your also correct that newer versions have larger maximums.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum unit required for storing any type of data in SQL Server is a Page, a page is `8 KB` in size.i.e exactly `8192 Bytes` , pages are stored in logical `Extents`.

**Page Header**

Yet not all of the `8192 Bytes` is available for data storage, some of the space from `8192 Bytes` is used to store information about the page itself. It is called `Page Header` and it is about `96 Bytes`.

**Row Set**

This is another section on the page containing information about the rows on that page, it begins at the end of the page taking another `36 Bytes` from the total page size `8192 Bytes`.

**Total Space Available for Data Storage**

```
8912   Total space on a page
- 96   Space taken by the page header
- 36   Space taken by the Row set
----------------------------------------------
8060   Total Space Available for Data Storage
```

---

So if you are trying to calculate the amount of data you will be able to store in a database and especially when you are talking in Terabytes, dont forget to take Page header and row set into consideration.